# Badges section gets strangely smaller and italic when user has no visible post

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, mobile-web

See the image. The "badges" section is smaller and wrongly italic and doesn't fit the screen.

> [image: Example of the incorrect rendering]

It has a <s>significantly higher</s> 100% chance of shrinking if the user has no visible posts.

I can reproduce this issue on Android 5.1 and 7.1, with Google Chrome version 52, 54, 57, 60, 61, 62 (all from Play Store).

This is what it *should* look like, with no left/right margin:

> [image: What it should look like]

If you want to see it yourself, here's [Jeff Atwood's profile on Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/163/jeff-atwood) (bugged) and [my profile on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/350567/idebug) (unbugged).

Comment: I don't understand this question... specifically the reference to something on your view "panicking". By the way, my view is different, with the badges left-aligned...

Comment: When reporting bugs better describe the actual bug, highlight relevant section in screenshot, etc. Not let us guess. I still don't really understand what bug you try to report.

Comment: Why still downvotes???

Comment: Why still upvotes??? ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Not a right place and right time to play this joke, though. I'm very depressed for being downvoted for such a (hopefully) good bug report.

Comment: If it helps: I have upvoted you. I noted this bug ages ago, but I stopped reporting them because there seems to be no one fixing those issues. Maybe therefore the community isn't that interested either.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Then why not vote the answer up altogether? ;)

Comment: Because I didn't feel like testing it if it works, which I usually do when I upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own analysis about the issue, with a practical solution supplied.

Maybe the badges section shouldn't belong to "`empty` posts"?

```html
<div class="empty">
  <h3>Keeping a low profile.</h3>
  <p>This user hasn&#39;t posted... yet.</p>

  <!-- MARK: div class="empty" should have ended here -->
  <!-- The following part belongs to another div -->

  <div class="user-panel _card">
    <div class="subheader _level-2">
      <div class="-title">
        <h2>Rarest badges <span>(1)</span></h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Badges section here -->
    ...

  </div>
</div><!-- / empty -->

<!-- Bug? "empty" shouldn't end here. It should be moved to MARK above -->
```

And this is the CSS part that's probably causing bad padding and wrong italic:

```css
.empty{padding:30px;text-align:center;font-style:italic;color:#848d95;font-size:11px}
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is the correct code from a not affected page (where a user has at least a visible post):

```html
<div class="user-panel _card js-top-posts">
  <!-- "Newest Posts" section -->
</div><!-- / user-panel card -->

<!-- The above div is correctly ended there and doesn't affect badges section -->

<div class="user-panel _card">
  <div class="subheader _level-2">
    <div class="-title">
      <h2>Rarest badges <span>(27)</span></h2>

      <!-- Continuing badges -->
      ...
```

So, a simple fix would be moving the closing `</div>` tag to the right place:

```html
<div class="empty">
  <h3>Keeping a low profile.</h3>
  <p>This user hasn&#39;t posted... yet.</p>
</div><!-- / empty -->
<!-- ^ Just move it there -->

<div class="user-panel _card">
  <div class="subheader _level-2">
```